# My JDBC code creates an exception when obtaining MetaData for result set

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm attempting to perform a query on my tables for an object with a particular key. I've tested this out in SQL with stored procedures and it works. Here is the JDBC code and the output -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re7Dy.png)

```java
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call project2.show_students_classes(?,?,?)}");
cs.setString(1, sid);
cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.execute();
System.out.println("Query executed");
String errMsg = cs.getString(2);
System.out.println("Err msg: " + errMsg);
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject(3);
System.out.println("Result obj acquired");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); <--- Exception thrown around here
System.out.println("Result obj metadata acquired");
int col = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) 
{
     System.out.println("Entering loop for column count at: "+ i);
     if (i > 1) { System.out.print(" | "); }
     System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
}
System.out.println();
while (rs.next()) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) { 
         System.out.println("Entering loop for column data at " +i);
         if (i > 1) { System.out.print("   "); }
         System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
cs.close();
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```sql
procedure show_students_classes(mySid in students.sid%type, errMsg out varchar2, myCursor out sys_refcursor) is
    counter int;
    counter2 int;
    begin
    select count(*) into counter2 from students where sid=mySid;
    if counter2=0
        then errMsg := 'Invalid Student ID!';  
    else
    select count(*) into counter from enrollments where sid=mySid; 
    if counter = 0
        then errMsg := 'The student has no courses';
    else 
        open myCursor for
        SELECT cl.classid, cl.dept_code || cl.course_no as DPT_COURSE_NO, co.title, cl.year, cl.semester
        FROM enrollments e right join classes cl 
        ON e.classid=cl.classid 
        INNER JOIN courses co 
        ON co.course_no=cl.course_no
        WHERE e.sid=mySid;
    DBMS_SQL.return_result(myCursor);
    end if;
    end if;
    end;
```

I threw in a bunch of print statements to help track where the exception is being thrown, and it doesn't get past the line with `ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData()`.

The exception stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mydemo3.showStudentsClasses(mydemo3.java:172)
    at mydemo3.main(mydemo3.java:238)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:404)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:179)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Line 172 is line I referred to above.

Comment: The exception contains the relevant information. You didn't paste it, making it very hard to help here.

Comment: You should post the _complete_ stack trace.

Comment: Oh I didnt think it was needed sorry about that

Comment: You still haven't posted the complete exception stacktrace, your stacktrace seems to be somewhere in the middle. A stacktrace starts with the exception name and message, followed by the call stack and zero or more "caused by" parts with their own exception name, message, and call stack. In addition, your question should contain a [mre], so all relevant data, minimal PSQL and Java code to reproduce the error.

Comment: While trying to condense the question I messed around with the formatting and removed the exception ... added it back in

Comment: The problem is that your stored procedure doesn't return a result set in the third parameter, but null. So when you dereference it without a null-check, that results in the NPE. You need to find out why, and we can't help you there because you haven't provided a [mre] that shows what your PL/SQL code does.

Comment: I saw that you did provide it in an earlier version, so I have rolled back your changes to remove that information.

Comment: Oh thanks I was in the process of trying to add it back, i wasnt sure how much information was too much so I appreciate the tips on trying to stay concise!

Comment: It looks to me like your stored procedure either returned the message "Invalid Student ID!" or "The student has no courses", in which case the cursor is null. You will need to handle the error result of your stored procedure appropriately by not dereferencing the result set when it is null.

Comment: Shouldn't i return a non null cursor if the key I passed in is in the table (given the else condition in the procedure) ? Also by handling the error result are you refering to checking if rs is null right after calling getObject?